# How to convert CSS to XML with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, xml, converters

I want to convert some CSS like this:

```css
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

#content {
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

into an XML structure like this:

```xml
<class name='body'>
<param name='margin'>0</param>
<param name='padding'>10px</param>
</class>

<class name='#content'>
<param name='background'>#ffffff</param>
</class>
```

I want to put the CSS in a `textarea` and let this convert to a second `textarea`. Is this possible?

My idea was to split the code into an array; with every class or id in an array with their attributes:

```
array [0][0][0] = body
array [0][1][0] = margin
array [0][1][1] = 0
array [0][2][0] = padding
array [0][2][1] = 10px 0
array [1][0][0] = #content
array [1][1][0] = background
array [1][1][1] = #ffffff
```

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: we are using xml for our cms to put some extra information on the css attributes like editable="yes" or "no". in this case you can edit this attributes in the backend of our cms.  But at first it´s easier to write normal css and convert the final css to xml.

Comment: Sure, a simple parsing and converting job; could be done in any language.

Comment: but css has no tag structure like <tag name="foo">. thats why i´m a little helpless how to seperate the classes.

Comment: Have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415755/css-to-xml-conversion

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code your looking for is pretty easy to find, but likely you've just been searching for the wrong thing.

I'd share my code with you, but it's written in a form that looks something like
minimized code that while allowing me to cram entire frameworks into a thimble without minimizing tends to be a bit confusing to those that don't want to marry it. Although,being able to write in 4-5 keystrokes what might 20 or 40 otherwise makes it a real fun date.

I have a section of code that allows me to among other things use CSS without bothering with browser prefixing as it takes care of that stuff on the fly, but there are things like modernizer and other even more CSS specific tools that perform a similar task and whose source code would probably be pretty easy to pillage the parser you need from.

I do have this bit from one of my older less compact versions that might help you along a little. The regex is part of breaking down the CSS into properties and values and while a little old should still be useful.

The for loop's body has some dependencies, but is really just tossed in to give you an idea of how that old regex was used. The new one is not way different but the code has gotten so tight it would be nearly impossible to extract a similar sample from. Come to think of it the whole section that loop is from has been boiled down to smaller than this loop.

```
RegExp(/(?:(?:[{;]{1,1})(?:[$]{0,})(?:[\s$\n\t]{0,}){0,})([-a-z]{1,1}[-a-z_0-9]{1,}?)(?=[ \t]{0,}[:])/gim)


for(;(a_prop=rx.rx_props.exec(s_textContent));)
{var    prop_in=(a_prop||[null,null])[1],prop_out=_.vcss$(prop_in,'-');
if(prop_in!=prop_out)
    {s_textContent=s_textContent.substr(0,rx.rx_props.lastIndex-    prop_in.length)+prop_out+s_textContent.substr(rx.rx_props.lastIndex);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it would make more sense to convert it into the following XML.

```
<style>
  <body margin="0 auto" padding="10px 0"/>
  <any id="content" background="#ffffff"/>
</style>
```

Note how the attributes `id` and `class` (not in your example) are treated differently to other attributes.  Note the new tagname `any`.  And finally, note that nested CSS styles like

```
table.a td {border:thin solid black; margin:1px}
```

translate naturally into child nodes.

```
<table class="a">
  <td border="thin solid black" margin="1px"/>
</table>
```